# Set Receive Intent back to Default Value in Android using Java

Tags: java, android

FirstActivity.java

```
startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class)
                    .putExtra("passed_value", true));
```

SecondActivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
         if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("passed_value", false)){

         }
    }
```

After receiving intent value from `FirstActivity.java` every reload it runs the  `if` block . But i need this intent to run only in `onPageFinished` method.

So how to run `if` block only when it comes from `FirstActivity.java`. Is there any way so that i can make this intent value back to default value after `if` block executed?

Answer (score 1):

A fairly straight forward method would be to have a `Boolean passedValue` variable that you instantiate with the intent extra in `onCreate`, and then set as false in the `if` block. Something along the following lines should work,

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Boolean passedValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        passedValue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("passed_value", false);
        //Other code things
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
         if(passedValue){
            //Do what you need to do
            passedValue = false
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `SecondActivity` create a class level variable as `boolean passed_value = false;`

Then in your `onCreate()`, change its value like - `passed_value = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("passed_value", false);`

Finally you can use it like -

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {
     if(passed_value){

     }
}
```